# What kind of red and black insect is in the photo?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I was wondering what kind of insect this was that I found on a flower on my deck this morning?

[image: ][1][1]]

The insect was in my flower pot on my deck. I took the picture from my cell phone and zoomed in for a clearer shot. The body of the insect (not counting the antennae) was about an inch.

Comment: Please provide your location, approx size of the insect, and any better photos if you have them. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

This is a nymph of some species of [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera), or true bug.

Specifically, this appears to be the nymph stage of a [**wheel bug**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_bug) (***Arilus cristatus***) or some other species in the family [Reduviidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduviidae).

[image]

<sup>Source: [David Larson](http://freepages.misc.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~larsonmorgan/True%20Bugs/Wheel%20Bug%20nymph%20(Arilus%20cristatus)%202.jpg)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Source: [Debbie Roos 2005](https://growingsmallfarms.ces.ncsu.edu/growingsmallfarms-farmphotojuly405/)</sup>

Here is a picture of an adult (with name-sake dorsal *wheel*):

[image]

<sup>Source: [Donald W. Hall](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/wheel_bug.htm)</sup>

You'll notice that the nymph is quite different looking:

> Nymphs have been described in detail by Readio (1927). Smaller nymphs are bright red with black marks. The last instar nymphs are darker. Nymphs lack the "wheel" or crest. For a diagnostic key to identify nymphs of the family Reduviidae to genus (including Arilus), see Fracker and Usinger (1949). [[Source](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/wheel_bug.htm)].

- If you're truly interested in accurately  IDing to genus/species, you might check out Fracker & Usinger 1949$^1$, [Herring & Ashlock 1971](http://journals.fcla.edu/flaent/article/view/56639/54318)$^2$, or papers that cite their work.

You can find more information about *A. cristatus* [here](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/wheel_bug.htm).

---

Citations:

1. <sup>Fracker S.B. & Usinger, R.L. 1949. The generic identification of Nearctic reduviid nymphs (Hemiptera). *Annals of the Entomological Society of America* 42: 273-278.</sup>
2. <sup>Herring, J.L. & Ashlock, P.D. 1971. A Key to the Nymphs of the Families of Hemiptera (Heteroptera) of America North of Mexico. *Florida Entomologist* 54: 207-212.</sup>