# Identification of fuzzy insect in Pennsylvania

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in south eastern Pennsylvania, USA. About a month ago I came across this very peculiar insect. Its body was about an inch long, it was fuzzy, and it had a long proboscis(?) and long orange legs.  I've been wondering about it ever since. Can anyone identify it?

[image: fuzzy big nosed insect]

Comment: Related: [What kind of red and black insect is in the photo?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/61178/16866)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the nymph of a bug (Hemiptera) from the Genus *Arilus*, probably [*Arilus cristatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_bug), also known as "wheel bug".

Here is another image of it, for comparison:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://bugguide.net/node/view/288330</sup>

And here is the adult:

[image]

<sup>Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_bug</sup>